# I am trying to subtract a value from a value in the previous row and next column over

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using pandas and reading a CSV file, I am trying to subtract a value from its previous rows diagonal. Going off the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49O0W.png), I want to subtract the 'Time in' from the previous rows 'Time Out' to calculate the time in minutes difference. I tried to use a few different variations of  df1.shift(periods=1, axis='columns') but could not figure out the way to complete this task. I do not think using shift is the concept I am looking for.

I appreciate any of the help! Please send me resources to read up on the concept as it will be important for a few other tasks I am trying to improve on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
df['diff'] = df['Time In'] - df['Time Out'].shift(1)
```

but make sure the dates are in a pandas datetime format first so they can correctly subtract

example:

```
   in  out  diff
0   5    1   NaN
1   6    2   5.0
2   7    3   5.0
3   8    4   5.0
```

either I'm reading your question wrong or its worded backwards, but subtracting Time In from previous row Time Out would give you for example: 11:30 - 11:45 so I think you want it the other way around...in any case you can use this method to either shift the column down using shift(1) or up using shift(-1)

Comment: I will look to implement this in the morning and update. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Sorry I had the question worded incorrectly. I was able to get it to work anyways. I appreciate the help!